# Вытягивается текст в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь на картинку добавить номер. Но возникает проблема - текст вытягивается вертикально. Видимо это из-за пропорций канваса. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно этого избежать и вставить текст в нормальных пропорциях?

```js
var popupCardBack = document.querySelector('.flex-popap-card');
src_back = 'https://telegra.ph/file/d74fb1644e815f0ee8a52.jpg';
      idBack = 'deck1';
popupCardBack.innerHTML += '<canvas id="' + idBack +
        '" style="max-width: 24vw; height: 39vw; margin: auto;"></canvas>'
      create_back(src_back, 1236, idBack)
 
function create_back (img_src, num, classId)
{
  var img=new Image();
  img.onload=function(){run()};
  img.src=img_src;
  function run(){
    var canv = document.getElementById(classId)
    var ctx= canv.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, canv.width, canv.height);
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fontFamily = "Casanova"
    ctx.textBaseline = "center";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.font = "90px Casanova";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    numStr = num.toString()
    ctx.fillText(numStr, canv.width / 2 - numStr.length / 2 * 3, canv.height / 2 + 30);
  }
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  display: none;
}
.overlay.active {
  display: block;
}

.overlay .flex-popap-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 6vh;
  padding-bottom: 6vh;
  padding-left: 6vw;
  padding-right: 6vw;
}
.overlay .flex-popap-card canvas {
padding: 0.5vh 0.5vh 0.5vh 0.5vh;
}
```

```html
<button>Клик</button
<div class="overlay" id="popupCards">
      <div class="flex-popap-card">
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно канвасу прописать ширину и высоту родную изображения `width="310px" height="432px"`. А в `style` ширину и высоту `100%`, далее управлять шириной в `style`

```js
var popupCardBack = document.querySelector('.flex-popap-card');
src_back = 'https://telegra.ph/file/d74fb1644e815f0ee8a52.jpg';
      idBack = 'deck1';
popupCardBack.innerHTML += '<canvas id="' + idBack +
        '" width="310px" height="432px" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></canvas>'
      create_back(src_back, 1236, idBack)
 
function create_back (img_src, num, classId)
{
  var img=new Image();
  img.onload=function(){run()};
  img.src=img_src;
  function run(){
    var canv = document.getElementById(classId)
    var ctx= canv.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, canv.width, canv.height);
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fontFamily = "Casanova"
    ctx.textBaseline = "center";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.font = "90px Casanova";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    numStr = num.toString()
    ctx.fillText(numStr, canv.width / 2 - numStr.length / 2 * 3, canv.height / 2 + 30);
  }
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  display: none;
  
}
.overlay.active {
  display: block;
  
}

.overlay .flex-popap-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 6vh;
  padding-bottom: 6vh;
  padding-left: 6vw;
  padding-right: 6vw;
}
.overlay {
padding: 0.5vh 0.5vh 0.5vh 0.5vh;
}
```

```html
<button>Клик</button
<div class="overlay" id="popupCards">
      <div class="flex-popap-card">
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Но в данном случае тогда изображение вытягивается в ширину, а мне нужно сохранить пропорции

Comment: @jurafenix Нужн было канвасу прописать width="310px" height="432px" помимо style

Comment: @jurafenix обновил ответ

Comment: @jurafenix А дальше уже в style управляйте пропорциями в процентах